# Create table from 3 another mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have tables

[image]

I have in the View 3 dropdown list

1. TeamName
2. Username
3. RoleName

When I click on Submit 
I need create table TeamUser in SQL try this - doesn t work

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        User user = new User();
        TeamUser tuser = new TeamUser();
        Session["userId"] = user.UserID;
        int.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString());
        Role rolUser = entity_dal.SelectRoleByName(Reguest.Form["roleId"]);
        tuser.RoleID = rolUser.RoleID; 
        tuser.CreateOn = DateTime.Now;
        tuser.TeamID = user.UserID;
        tuser.TeamID = int.Parse(Request.Form["teamId"]);
        try
        {
           entity_dal.InsertUser(tuser);
        }
        catch (Exception Exception) { ViewBag.error = Exception.InnerException + "--" + Exception.Message; }


        return View();
    }
```

and next View I need input table like (all users belong that Team)

| User Name     |  TeamName    |  Delete  |  Edit

Where error in my Controller and help me please create View

Thank you